Allowed to say salaam while in prayer, yet not during khutbah? Does anyone else find this odd?
Assalaam-u-alaykum,
I was watching a YouTube video (watch from 5:49 to 6:17) by Muslim Lantern: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zt5aWPQGa0A&start=348&end=377
During prayer, it's apparently a sunnah to return salaam to a fellow Muslim if acknowledging their salaam by signaling with the palm of your hand. This is referenced is Sunan Abu Dawood, Book 2, Hadith Number 0927; Narrated Abdullah ibn Umar: https://sunnah.com/abudawud:927
My question is if the salaam is given such importance during a prayer (when you should have most concentration and are speaking directly with your creator), why is returning the salaam of a fellow Muslim not allowed during Friday khutbah when everyone is listening to the surmon by a khateeb, which is also obligatory to the jhummah prayer?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JNtXldFs1yQ
https://islamqa.info/en/answers/45651/is-talking-during-khutbah-permissible
I'm a little perplexed by this upon discovering this dichotomy. Does anyone know why there are differences here? May Allah guide us all and only He knows best. Jazakallah Khairan.

There is difference of opinion among the madhabs on the ruling on replying during prayer by signalling and also on the ruling of replying during the sermon - it is possible that the two sources you linked follow different madhabs. A person initiating the greeting is transgressing as he himself is obligated to remain silent and to listen to the sermon. However during prayer the person initiating the greeting is not doing any such thing.

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

@UmH please consider answering the question since comments are not meant to last forever!
